# Integrate a facebook c# sdk login system into an existing login system based on Microsoft Membership Api

Tags: asp.net-membership, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to figure out how should I integrate facebook login system in my existing application through **facebook c# sdk.**

I have a web forms application and I'm authenticating users by standard **Login** control.

I'm using  **MembershipProvider**, RoleProvider and ProfileProvider.

I'm thinking I should persist FacebookUniqueID and put it into relation with existing informations on my Membership Users table.

I'm wondering wich is a correct approach to this.

Considering I have a custom Profile Provider that uses a custom sql table, it would be fast to add a FacebookUniqueID property to my user profiles and use it in my login workflow:

- Login through facebook;
- retrieve facebookUniqueID;
- retrieve userName for the user that
  have this specific facebookUniqueID,
  then

  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, bool);

What about providing an overload for the previous method taking facebookUniqueID as parameter?

Please let me know what do you think about this from any perspective and if anyone knows a simple working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. We implement a similar solution (though we have rolled our own custom membership/role/profile etc and don't use the built in approach.)

You also will have to handle the situations that occur when a new user (without an existing account) logs into your site via Facebook.